Spring boot octet-stream not supported for PUT endpoint having image file and JSON details in formdata
I'm building a spring boot application with PUT endpoint to consume the image file and some customer details using below code.
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ProfileDetails> updateProfileDetails(@RequestPart("profile_details") UpdateProfileDetailsRequest updateProfileDetailsRequest,
                                                                  @RequestPart("profile_image") MultipartFile profileImage,
                                                                  @PathVariable("id") String profileId){
   
    var updatedProfile = service.updateProfileDetails(new UpdateProfileDetailsRequest(),profileId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedProfile);
}

And now the frontend react application is consuming this API by sending profile_details and profile_image in formData like below.
profile_details: {"email_id":"xxxxxxx@icloud.com"}
profile_image: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4QBaRXhpZgAATU

I'm able to see this request body in the chrome inspect mode, and it's also sending the content type header as formdata
  content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryYBCGyw8abCFWMGh9

But for some reason the app is failing with below error, I couldn't find more information on consuming the JSON data and file in the same api 
[nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported]


Assume var updatedProfile is of type UpdateProfileDetailsRequest can you add the POJO definition as well

While doing more research i found this post which is helpful to follow the path were we need to send the JSON and IMAGE in blob format from reactjs app, but that answers in the post didn't have the latest code to send them in blob format. I have updated the code in reactjs application as below
const updatedData = {email_id: 'xxxxx@icloud.com'}
const updatedDataBlob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(updatedData)], {
            type: 'application/json'
          });
const imageBlob = new Blob([profileImage], { type: profileImage.type });
formDataBody.append('profile_details', updatedDataBlob);
formDataBody.append('profileImage', imageBlob);

const response = await academyApiAxios.put(`/profiles/${profileId}`, formDataBody, {headers:{'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}});


Pass the updateProfileDetailsRequest properly to the service:
In your code, you're creating a new UpdateProfileDetailsRequest object and passing it to the service. You should pass the existing one, i.e., updateProfileDetailsRequest, instead of creating a new instance.
